# Javascript. Sorting array of objects by property x

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I want to draw objects one by one sorted by y value, so objects that are "closer" won't be drawn behind objects that have lower y. I have array like this:

```
 List.list = [
 'idofobject' : {
  x: 20,
  y: 28
 },
 'otheridofobject' : {
  x: 20,
  y: 23
 },

];
```

How can i sort it by object y value? I tried to sort it like normal array of objects, but in this case i have id of object before properties, so it wasnt possible. How can i do this without deleting id of object?

Comment: Your List.list is incorrect, but this is answer is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: Arrays can't have keys. Your list is a syntax error.

Comment: Hmmm, but it works well. I just cant sort it :/

Comment: Could i sort it if i changed [] to {}?

Answer (score 3):

On one line

```
list.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.y - obj2.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.Prototype.sort` function like so :

```
List.list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.y - b.y;
});
```

This will sort using a custom function.

Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if you need more informations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use if you want underscore

http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: link only answers are of very little value. Provide relevant code based on link and only use link to support what is actually in the answer

Comment: Ok, I think the code in the link more clear imposible. But I appreciate your comment.